# scope of content types

Tags: visual-studio, content-type

I was reading on content types and I see that share point allows allows to create them at site collection and list level scope.

My question is that in visual studio where can we specify whether this is a site collection level or a list level content type? Because the scope of feature is either webap, site, farm or web.

Is there a way to do this via UI?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure all content type definitions created in VS are, by default, site content types.

There is no attribute in the [Content Type element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544268(v=office.15).aspx) of a content type definition that allows you to target a specific list.

<del>Even if you were going to [create a list definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023(v=office.15).aspx) declaritively in VS, to include a content type in the list you would have to create a content type definition separately, and then base the list definition off the content type definition.  But because the content type definition is separate, it will still be deployed as a site content type.</del>

If you want to create a site content type from the UI, you would go to Site Settings, then Site Content Types (under Galleries), and create a new one there.

If you want to create a list content type, you would have to go to the List Settings page for the particular list, go to Advanced Settings and allow the management of content types, then add a pre-existing site content type to the list, and then edit the list level copy of that content type.

**EDIT**

It seems I was wrong.  According to this MSDN article on [Site and List Content Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms463016(v=office.14).aspx):

> You can create a content type collection for a new list as part of the
>   list definition before list instances are provisioned. Within the list
>   definition's ContentTypes element, you can reference existing site
>   content types, and you can also define new content types. In this
>   case, the new content types are available only to list instances that
>   are created from the same list definition. The new content types are
>   not part of the site collection and are not available to other lists.

So it seems that you *can* create list scoped content types through a list definition created in VS.

Comment: So it looks like the only way to do this is from UI. There is no way to create list scoped content types via VS?

Comment: Apparently there is, see my edit.